# TF-IDF score calculation example

Tags: cluster-analysis

I want to calculate tf-idf score of a sentence where already many sentences are present in the cluster. I have already saw some examples where only two sentences as example. But i need more than two sentences. can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TF-IDF is defined on two documents or sentences (two word vectors).
You seem to want to apply it one-vs-many?

There is no theoretically backed approach for this. But you can use any of the heuristics common in HAC, because that appears to be what you are reinventing.